# ImportError: No module named 'keras.utils.visualize_util'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

Hi when I am trying to run a code in keras it is showing me the following error:

```
from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
ImportError: No module named 'keras.utils.visualize_util'
```

How can I solve this? thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You will have to either fix the code manually, or downgrade Keras.

By looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commits/master/keras/utils/vis_utils.py) of that module, you can see that it was renamed on February 28, 2017 from `visualize_util` to `vis_utils`. The `plot` function was also renamed to `plot_model`.

You will have to update the code to reflect these changes, or use a proper Keras version where the code you are using was developed or tested.

Comment: Thank you very much. you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 19):

Tensorflow 2:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```py
from keras.utils import plot_model
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this:

from tensorflow.keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

Use this instead:

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical